# spring security - how to provide a list of intercepting URL's

Tags: java, xml, spring, model-view-controller, spring-security

In my spring project having a bunch of users and User Levels. so that need to provide a list of intercepting url's and its access control. currently it is written in spring security xml file. how can i make it simple to do?

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: You have to provide them _somewhere_. What's wrong with the XML? (besides it's being a little 2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be if you want to put them in application properties, then use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

in  **application.properties**

```
url1 = /admin
url2 = /reservation/**
```

===

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${url1}")
private String url1;

@Value("${url1}")
private String url2;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      //..
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(url1).access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers(url2).access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') ;

    }
}
```